# Is there a way to print the the webpage page title when I type {page_title} on my html website?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a website on Wordpress, I have to make fifty pages for each American state *(e.g domain.com/Alabama)*, I want to type type a variable that changes into "Alabama" and so so on for each state, so I want to print the page title against a variable. *(e.g if I type `<h2>Services in {page_title}</h2>` on this page "domain.com/Alabama"  it should give me "Services in Alabama")*

I am trying this `get_the_title( int|WP_Post $post )`

I am getting blank space...

Comment: Take a look at https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the loop you can use:

```
the_title();
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title